# Set Pandas Value Based on Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I would like to replace the value of a Dataframe with the Value from A dictionary.
In plain english: If There is a value in `Column C` that matches a Dictionary Key, then Replace `Column D` with the value in the Dictionary that corresponds to that specific key.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfp = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,3,4,5,5,3,1,5,np.NaN], 
                    'B' : [1,0,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : ['AA1233445','A9875', 'rmacy','Idaho Rx','Ab123455','TV192837','RX','Ohio Drugs','RX12345','USA Pharma'], 
                    'D' : [123456,123456,1234567,12345678,12345,12345,12345678,123456789,1234567,np.NaN],
                    'E' : ['Assign','Unassign','Assign','Ugly','Appreciate','Undo','Assign','Unicycle','Assign','Unicorn',]})
print(dfp)

z = {'rmacy': 999}
dfp.loc[dfp['C'].isin(z.keys()), 'D' ] = z.values() # <--- code to change

Output: 
     A    B           C            D           E
0  NaN  1.0   AA1233445       123456      Assign
1  NaN  0.0       A9875       123456    Unassign
2  3.0  3.0       rmacy        (999)      Assign #<--- Worked with paranthesis
3  4.0  5.0    Idaho Rx  1.23457e+07        Ugly
4  5.0  0.0    Ab123455        12345  Appreciate
5  5.0  0.0    TV192837        12345        Undo
6  3.0  NaN          RX  1.23457e+07      Assign
7  1.0  9.0  Ohio Drugs  1.23457e+08    Unicycle
8  5.0  0.0     RX12345  1.23457e+06      Assign
9  NaN  0.0  USA Pharma          NaN     Unicorn
```

The above code works (except is puts the value in Paranthesis. But if the dictionary is larger than one key, it will put both values in `Column D` because there are two matches in the column.

```
     A    B           C            D           E
0  NaN  1.0   AA1233445       123456      Assign
1  NaN  0.0       A9875       123456    Unassign
2  3.0  3.0       rmacy   (999, 333)      Assign
3  4.0  5.0    Idaho Rx  1.23457e+07        Ugly
4  5.0  0.0    Ab123455        12345  Appreciate
5  5.0  0.0    TV192837        12345        Undo
6  3.0  NaN          RX   (999, 333)      Assign
7  1.0  9.0  Ohio Drugs  1.23457e+08    Unicycle
8  5.0  0.0     RX12345  1.23457e+06      Assign
9  NaN  0.0  USA Pharma          NaN     Unicorn
```

How would one resolve this?

Comment: Greatly underrated question. Upvote on sight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `map` and `fillna`

```
dfp.assign(D=dfp.C.map(z).fillna(dfp.D))

     A    B           C            D           E
0  NaN  1.0   AA1233445     123456.0      Assign
1  NaN  0.0       A9875     123456.0    Unassign
2  3.0  3.0       rmacy        999.0      Assign
3  4.0  5.0    Idaho Rx   12345678.0        Ugly
4  5.0  0.0    Ab123455      12345.0  Appreciate
5  5.0  0.0    TV192837      12345.0        Undo
6  3.0  NaN          RX   12345678.0      Assign
7  1.0  9.0  Ohio Drugs  123456789.0    Unicycle
8  5.0  0.0     RX12345    1234567.0      Assign
9  NaN  0.0  USA Pharma          NaN     Unicorn
```

Comment: You always give the correct answer! haha. Could you walk me through the approach? How using `fillna()` gives the correct result is blowing my mind.

Comment: @MattR `map` returns the value from the dictionary if there is one, otherwise it returns `NaN`.  Then I fill those `NaN` with `fillna(df.D)`.  Then I overwrite the current `df.D` with these new values.

Comment: Simply brilliant... I hope I'm as fluent as you someday. Cheers!

Comment: You just inspired me to read some documentation and I just came up with another answer. how does `dfp.loc[(dfp['C'].isin([x[0] for x in z.items()])), 'D'] = [x[1] for x in z.items()]` compare. Would this be a viable option in your opinion?

Comment: @MattR no, that wouldn't work.  `(dfp['C'].isin([x[0] for x in z.items()]))` checks for membership in the keys of `z`... that's fine. and you are pointing to `'D'`... that's good too.  But you are assigning a list of values which may not be the same length as the number of rows with `'C'` values in the keys... (getting dizzy).

Comment: haha my head is spinning just trying to understand that. But essentially you are correct, if there are records with the same value, say `rmacy` I get the error `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable` as you expected.