# Replace values in a dataframe column, based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have two DataFrames:

```
df1
PRA_Kod;WorkerId
1049;9024
0014;60260
0608;10506
20270/9;20270
9511;64473
0639;60264
0767;10509
.. .. .. . .
df2
WorkerId;Day;Time;W
1049;11;u.wyp;WE
1049;14;u.wyp;WE
64454;11;u.wyp;WE
0014;15;u.wyp;WE
64471;12;u.wyp;WE
64471;13;u.wyp;WE
0639;06;u.wyp;WE
0639;01;u.wyp;WE
0639;02;u.wyp;WE
0639;03;u.wyp;WE
64465;04;u.wyp;WE
64465;05;u.wyp;WE
 ... ... .. .
```

I need to change the value in the column `df2['WorkerId']` to the value `df1['WorkerId']` if `df2['WorkerId']` appears in `df1['PRA_Kod']`.

*A note: `PRA_Kod` value "20270/9" is no typo. These tables result from combining data from different tables. Some users happen to have different indexes accross different tables.*

**Desired output:**

```
df_result
WorkerId;Day;Time;W
9024;11;u.wyp;WE
9024;14;u.wyp;WE
64454;11;u.wyp;WE
60260;15;u.wyp;WE
64471;12;u.wyp;WE
64471;13;u.wyp;WE
60264;06;u.wyp;WE
60264;01;u.wyp;WE
60264;02;u.wyp;WE
60264;03;u.wyp;WE
64465;04;u.wyp;WE
64465;05;u.wyp;WE
... ... .. .
```

How can this be done?

My attempt below results raises `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects.`

```
df_result.loc[ df2['WorkerId'].eq == df1['PRA_Kod'].eq, 
               df2['WorkerId']                         ] = df1['WorkerId']
```

Comment: `query` can do this.  https://www.statology.org/pandas-extract-column-value-based-on-another-column/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your line, is that

- you mean to use df1 as a *dictionary* (look for a value in one column, then get the value in the second column on the same row),
- but what you do in fact when you write `==`, is requesting a screening for a row-by-row match of both columns in df1 and df2.

Things will go much smoother when you first adapt df1 for use as dictionary.

---

**Method:**

1. Convert dataframe df1 into a dictionary where *key* : *val* pairs are *PRA_Kod* : *WorkerId*, as in [Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26716616/12846804)
2. Map this dictionary onto dataframe df2, as in [Set Pandas Value Based on Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43503962/1284680)

---

**1. Dictionary**

It's not directly `df1.to_dict()`, see? Either we write a loop, or we transpose it and rework columns and index, so that key:value pairs do land as needed:

```py
map_dict = df1.set_index('PRA_Kod').T.to_dict('records')[0]

{'1049': '9024',
 '0014': '60260',
 '0608': '10506',
 '20270/9': '20270',
 '9511': '64473',
 '0639': '60264',
 '0767': '10509'}
```

**2. Map**

The mapping finds cells that are also dictionary keys, and replaces those with dictionary values. Other cells are kept as they were.

```py
df_result = df2.assign(WorkerId = df2.WorkerId.map(map_dict).fillna(df2.WorkerId))

   WorkerId Day   Time   W
0      9024  11  u.wyp  WE
1      9024  14  u.wyp  WE
2     64454  11  u.wyp  WE
3     60260  15  u.wyp  WE
4     64471  12  u.wyp  WE
5     64471  13  u.wyp  WE
6     60264  06  u.wyp  WE
7     60264  01  u.wyp  WE
8     60264  02  u.wyp  WE
9     60264  03  u.wyp  WE
10    64465  04  u.wyp  WE
11    64465  05  u.wyp  WE
```

---

Refer to each linked question for more details about how both steps work. Without finding this method for step 2, I might have gone for an `np.where`, testing for value `.isin` dictionary keys.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is my third python program. While looking for information, I saw df.to_dict() and map and np.where but no one explained it like you did. Thanks for the clarification.